# Enjoy or enjoys?

Tags: word-order, tense-agreement

Should one write:

> Anyone who studies regularly will do better and **enjoy** it more.

OR

> Anyone who studies regularly will do better and **enjoys** it more.

To make the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It has to be plain *enjoy*, since that is conjoined with *do* as the complement of *will*: "will do better and [will] enjoy it more".

Comment: @StoneyB Surely that's worth a bit more of a StoneyB explanation as an answer! :)

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not wholly convinced. *Anyone who studies regularly enjoys it more* is fine. So what's wrong with extending that to *Anyone who studies regularly enjoys it more and will do better*? And then what's wrong with changing the sequence? You don't *have* to assume a deleted ***will*** in OP's version - it's just "clumsy", particularly that way round.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I'm not sure English allows this change of sequence without introducing ungrammaticality.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are right, in theory. But it seems to me that would be to make this not merely clumsy but garden-pathy: *will* establishes an expectation that what follows is not merely an ordinary future consequence but a future consequence of future studies, too. It re-categorizes *studies* as future-referent, then requires the hearer to re-re-categorze *studies* as present-referent.

Comment: Just possibly we could understand it as: "Anyone who studies regularly (will do better) and (enjoys it more)", but that is far-fetched. Just just possibly we could reverse the terms: "Anyone who studies regularly (enjoys it more) and (will do better)".

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm certainly not *defending* the "mixed tense" usage (it's clumsy/awkward in the extreme). I'm simply making the point that this is a matter of ***style/elegance/clarity*** rather than "grammatically correct". Which it seems to me is essential for a learner to grasp, because if they mistakenly think there's some kind of "grammatical rule" involved here I really can't see how they could ever hope to identify and learn it.

Comment: **Anyone who studies regularly will do better-- and enjoys it more** makes the sentence read a lot better. The dash clears up the confusion caused by this particular word order.

Comment: I disagree. The dash doesn't separate the "enjoys" from the "will do" enough to prevent the reader from stumbling as the tense swaps back and forth. The dash reads like a pause-for-effect, not a signal that "studies" is the verb "enjoys" is supposed to agree with. The order of the words matters in this sentence, and there's really no way around it.

Comment: @A.Beth you're right. I think I reconstructed the *first* sentence with a dash and said wow that sounds good! My bad.

Comment: The first one definitely looks good with a dash, yes! It's a good pause for effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take the discussion in the comments to an answer...

*"Anyone who studies regularly will do better and enjoys it more."* is wrong, because the placement of "*will do*" becomes what "enjoy" must match, not "studies."

E.g.,
-Anyone who studies regularly *will do better*.
-Anyone who studies regularly *will enjoy it more.*

Changing up the sequence, in English, really can change up the meaning, because (most of the time) verbs want to agree with the closest verb preceding them.

So you have to have: "Anyone who studies regularly will do better and enjoy it more."

If you use FumbleFingers' example, "Anyone who studies regularly enjoys it more and will do better," notice that sentence is matching "studies/enjoys," and the "will do" is connected by a conjunction that allows it to break tense from the prior verbs. (However, I would *avoid* using this sentence because "studies regularly enjoys" could be interpreted two ways: "anyone who studies, regularly enjoys it more" vs. "anyone who studies regularly, enjoys it more." Making your reader parse out the intended meaning will slow the reader down, when you want to carry the reader smoothly to your desired conclusion.)

Comment: +1 *Word order* actually does make a difference in English. And the point about a particular word order forcing the reader to slow down is nice. Also I just thought of using a dash. See my other comment.

Comment: @δοῦλος I fear I disagree with you strongly on that one! The dash *doesn't* help. Sorry!